# What's the working directory in Jenkins after executing a shell command box?

Tags: jenkins, working-directory

I'm looking at a Jenkins job and trying to understand it.

I have an **Execute shell** command box in my **Build** section:

```
> mkdir mydir 
> cd mydir
> 
> svn export --force https://example.com/repo/mydir .
```

When Jenkins is done executing that command, and moves on to the next build step, what is its working directory?
`workspece-root/` or `workspace-root/mydir` ?

As the next step, I have **Invoke top-level Maven targets** (still in the **Build** section).

What I really want to know is: why does that execute successfully?
Is it because Jenkins automatically moves back to the `workspace-root/` folder after executing a shell command box, or is it because the next job is a "top-level" job, and Jenkins therefore changes back to the `workspace-root/`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Each `build step` is a separate process that Jenkins spawns off. They don't share anything, neither current directory, nor environment variables set/changed within the `build step`. Each new `build step` starts by spawning a new process off the parent process (the one running Jenkins)

It's not that Jenkins "move back" to `$WORKSPACE`. It's that Jenkins **discards** the previous session.

Comment: Does it always start in $WORKSPACE, then? And could you maybe point me to a section in the official docs explaining that, please? :)

Comment: Yes, always `$WORKSPACE`. Most plugins will always be relative to `$WORKSPACE` too. If you click on the question mark icon to the right of `execute shell` build step, the pop up help mentions that it executes relative to `$WORKSPACE`

Answer (score 0):

I lately saw that if you print the CWD , I would get the Project_NAME.
E.g 
D:\jenkins\workspace\My_Project

Any script you might be running wont be found. Hence we can do a "CD path" before we start out scripts.

Answer (score 0):

`Slav`'s explanation is very good and I thought of complementing it by providing a real world example that shows how multiple Windows batch commands look like even if they work in the same directory:

#### Command 1

```
REM #ensures that all npm packages are downloaded
cd "%WORKSPACE%"
npm install
```

#### Command 2

```
REM #performs a prod-mode build of the project
cd "%WORKSPACE%"
ng build --prod --aot=true -environment=pp
```

So, each one ensure that current working directory points to the current project directory.